# Effort unit testing Entity framework 6.1.3 DB-first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, effort

I am experiencing problems when using Effort framework (version 1.1.4) to unit test my DB-layer.

I have a DB-layer using Entity framework 6.1.3 and the model is created using database-first approach so there is an `*.edmx` file describing the model.

I have created a partial class to expose an additional constructor used by the unit tests with effort like this:

```
public partial class Entities
{
    public Entities(DbConnection connection)
        : base(connection, true)
    {
    }
}
```

The simple unit-test looks like this:

```
    private Entities CreateContext()
    {
        //var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Entities"].ConnectionString;
        //var connection = Effort.EntityConnectionFactory.CreateTransient(connectionString);
        //return new Entities(connection as DbConnection);

        var connection = Effort.EntityConnectionFactory.CreatePersistent("name=Entities");
        var context = new Entities(connection);
        return context;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Testing_Effort_Integration()
    {
        using (var context = CreateContext())
        {
            var entity = context.TableEntity.FirstOrDefault(i=> i.Id);
            Assert.IsNotNull(entity);
        }
    }
```

When I run the unit test it throws an exception for the line:

```
var connection  = Effort.EntityConnectionFactory.CreatePersistent("name=Entities");
```

> {"The provider did not return a ProviderManifest instance."}
>   InnerException Message: {"Could not determine storage version; a valid
>   storage connection or a version hint is required."}

Other posts I have found suggests to change the `ProviderManifestToken` attribute in the `*.edmx` file from "2012" to "2008". This seems to solve the problem but instead gives my another exception when trying to use the context for the first time here:

```
var entity = context.TableEntity.FirstOrDefault(i=> i.Id);
```

> NotSupportedException Unable to determine the provider name for
>   provider factory of type
>   'System.Data.EntityClient.EntityProviderFactory'. Make sure that the
>   ADO.NET provider is installed or registered in the application config.

Anyone know how to solve this issue so I can use Effort with entity framework 6.1.3 DB-first approach?

I have successfully been able to use Effort (version 1.1.4) to unit test DB-layers created in EF 4 and EF 5 with DB-first approach - this is why I think that the EF-version can be of interest...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A colleague of mine found the solution to my issue!

Apparently I was using the "Effort" nuget package instead of the "Effort.EF6" nuget package. After uninstalling and installing the other I also had to update my App.Config with the tags:

```
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="Effort.Provider" invariant="Effort.Provider" description="Effort.Provider" type="Effort.Provider.EffortProviderFactory,Effort" />  
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>

  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="Effort.Provider" type="Effort.Provider.EffortProviderServices, Effort" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

And I also included a call in the SetUp for my unit tests to register the effort provider:

```
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        EffortProviderConfiguration.RegisterProvider();
    }
```

This solved the issue for my. Hopefully it can provide some help to others!

Comment: After doing this I get the following error: 

``System.InvalidOperationException: The Entity Framework provider type 'MyProject.Tests.EffortProviderFactory, MyProject.Tests, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' did not have a static property or field named 'Instance'. Entity Framework providers must declare a static property or field named 'Instance' that returns the singleton instance of the provider.``